# How to split cell content into rows by paragraph in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a text in a single cell of table in Microsoft Office word image below that represents one cell of table in Microsoft Office Word

[image]

I want to split the cell into multiple rows by paragraph, such that outcome should be

```
1   Aaatika Arif    Form–III
```

in a single table row and similarly all text rows visible in image should be shifted to their own table rows.

Comment: Thanks @MátéJuhász for you timely and valuable feedback. I got the idea through your answer. This is really perfect if the rows required are only 4. Actual number is bigger like 150. I am expecting some way that should not need text pasting in separate rows manually. Like we do not need to cut and paste text into table cells when using "Convert Text to Table" option under "Insert (tab) > Table".

Comment: If you have only one cell in your table, then you can convert it to text, then back to table. If either that doesn't work, then I don't see any good solution:(

Comment: @MátéJuhász, given the number of paragraphs involved, that really is the best, most manageable solution and deserves to be given as an actual answer, I think.

Comment: @cnread: it works only if that's the only cells in the table (or only one column and all cells need to be splited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. split cells

   - Select the cell you need to split
   - go to "table tools" - layout
   - click "split cells"
   - set desired number of columns / rows (1 / 4 in your case)
   - click "ok"
   - this will insert new rows, but keep text in the first one

before:
[image]

after:
[image]

2. distribute text

   - select the text you want to split
   - right-click and cut (CTRL+X)
   - select all the rows you want to fill
   - right-click and paste (CTRL+V)

Comment: thank you so much. You have solved my problem by suggesting second option of "distribute text".

Answer (score 1):

Although I usually use the **Split Cells** command, as Máté Juhász suggests, another way to do this is to use Word's Draw Table tool.

Select the table, or make sure that the cursor is somewhere inside it, and then, on the **Table Tools** > **Layout** tab, in the **Draw** group, click **Draw Table**.

[image: Draw Table button on the Table Tools > Layout tab]

Then just draw in horizontal lines between the paragraphs that you want to split into rows. Word will break the single cell into multiple rows.

Note, however, that the Draw Table tool is a bit fussy. If you don't draw the line in just the right place between paragraphs, you end up with extra rows or rows inserted between paragraphs other than the ones that you intended.

**Tip:** I always find that I need to basically draw right through the middle of the text in each paragraph to get the tool to work the way I want. So, to get the table to divide between paragraphs 1 and 2, draw through the middle of the line of text in paragraph 1. Then draw through the middle of the text in paragraph 2 to divide the table between paragraphs 2 and 3, and so on.

You'll probably also end up with extra space at the bottom of the last row, as shown below. In this case, just drag the bottom border upward until the extra space disappears. (Be sure to turn off the Draw Table tool first, either by clicking the button again or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.)

[image: Extra space at the bottom of the last row]

**Update:** I was assuming that your screenshot reflected the actual size of your tables. If, as you say, you're dealing with tables that have 150 paragraphs, this solution, which would otherwise be very quick (once you become accustomed to the tool), will obviously be too much work.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort to provide me the solution. You said rightly in update that you assumed that my screenshot reflected the actual size of table. But fact is that I selected only 4 lines to be shown in screenshot and actual are more than 4.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but one row with two columns, each of which had many paragraphs of text I wanted to split.

I selected and copied all text in both columns, then pasted it into a new blank Excel file, and it automatically split those paragraphs into rows. I then selected the cells in Excel and copied-and-pasted them into Word - that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to past many lines of text into a Word table so that each line is a new row, this worked perfectly for me AND it retains formatting such as highlighting. It is a pretty fast solution, too (no macros, no Excel, just common Word commands). I couldn't find this advice anywhere, not even from Bing AI Copilot.

1. Copy the lines of text and, in a separate word document, paste the text.
2. Convert text to table.
3. **IF** you have a multi-column table, this makes sure your text goes into the desired column: Add blank COLUMNS as needed to match the target table. I had seven columns and only one column needed the text, so I added blank columns to the left and right to make it match the target table I was going to paste into (using the ribbon command to add columns).
4. Copy the text from this new table, selecting **ALL ROWS**, even the blank ones.
5. Position your curser in the first cell of a blank row and PASTE with right click "INSERT NEW ROWS."
   That's it.
6. If the text size is wrong (if you are carrying over formatting from the source document to the target table), update Normal to match selection if size of text is wrong (using styles).